# Split join excel to create a new string from 2 different fields

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have issue which I can solve in google sheet but not in excel

Cell A2:  car_#.wheel_#.brake_#

I have in cell b2:  abc.3.2

and I would like to get the following in result:

car_abc.wheel_3.brake_2

in a google sheet, I have solved it by

`=ArrayFormula(TRIM(JOIN("",SPLIT(A2,"_#")&"_"&split(B2,"."))))`

Is there any way to get something similar to work in excel?

Answer (score 1):

This is what I have ***tried***, assuming you are using **O365**

[image: FORMULA_SOLUTION]

---

• Formula used in cell **C2** --> Applicable to **O365 Insiders Beta Channel Users Only**

```
=TEXTJOIN("",,TEXTSPLIT(A2,"_#",,1)&"_"&TEXTSPLIT(B2,"."))
```

---

• Formula used in cell **D2** --> Applicable to **Excel 2019, Excel 2021 & O365 Users**

```
=TEXTJOIN("",,FILTERXML("<t><s>"&SUBSTITUTE(A2,"_#","</s><s>")&"</s></t>","//s[node()]")
&"_"&FILTERXML("<t><s>"&SUBSTITUTE(B2,".","</s><s>")&"</s></t>","//s[node()]"))
```